# How to close dropdown box view on open another? [React - Native]

Tags: react-native, react-native-dropdown-picker

I am using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker) to implement dropdown option. I have multiple dropdown view in a screen. All are showing nicely but the problem is when one box view is opened I am going to open another dropdown. In that time both boxes are in open state.

What I want to achieve? - When one box is opened and I clicked another dropdown to open previous dropdox box will automatically get closed. How could I achieve that?

[image: Showing dropdowns]

[image: Both boxes are opened]

Below is my code of two dropdown-

```
<View style={{ marginRight: 8, marginLeft: 8, marginBottom: 3 }}>

                               <View style={{ width: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 12 }}>
                                    <View style={{ width: '100%', height: CONSTANTS.windowHeight * 0.0755, }}>

                                    </View>

                                    <DropDownPicker
                                         zIndex={3000}
                                         zIndexInverse={1000}
                                         searchable={true}
                                         onOpen={() => { this.setState({ dropdown_visible: false }), console.log("opened"), this.stateOpen()  }}
                                         // onClose={() => this.setState({ dropdown_visible: false })}
                                         // style = {{marginTop: 50}}
                                         open={this.state.state_open}

                                         containerStyle={{ position: 'absolute', height: CONSTANTS.windowHeight * 0.07, alignSelf: 'center', left: 1, right: 1 }}
                                         itemStyle={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}
                                         dropDownStyle={{ borderColor: CONSTANTS.COLOR.BASE_COLOR, backgroundColor: CONSTANTS.COLOR.DROPDOWN_BACKGROUND, textAlign: 'flext-start' }}
                                         items={states}
                                         placeholder="Select State"
                                         placeholderStyle={{
                                              color: 'gray',
                                              textAlign: 'left'
                                         }}
                                         controller={instance => this.controller = instance}
                                         onChangeList={(states, callback) => {
                                              this.setState({
                                                   states // items: items
                                              }, callback);
                                         }}

                                         defaultValue={this.state.value}
                                         onChangeItem={(item, index) => (this.setState({
                                              state_name: item.value, state_id: states_with_id[index].id
                                         }), this.getCity(states_with_id[index].id))}
                                    />
                               </View>

                          </View>


                          <View style={{ marginRight: 8, marginLeft: 8, marginBottom: 3 }}>

                               <View style={{ width: '100%', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 12 }}>
                                    <View style={{ width: '100%', height: CONSTANTS.windowHeight * 0.0755 }}>

                                    </View>

                                    <DropDownPicker
                                         zIndex={2000}
                                         zIndexInverse={2000}
                                         controller={instance => controller = instance}
                                         searchable={true}
                                         onOpen={() => { this.setState({ dropdown_visible: false }), this.cityOpen() }}
                                         // onClose={() => this.setState({ dropdown_visible: false })}
                                         // style = {{marginTop: 50}}
                                         open={this.state.city_open}
                                         containerStyle={{ position: 'absolute', height: CONSTANTS.windowHeight * 0.0755, alignSelf: 'center', left: 1, right: 1 }}
                                         itemStyle={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start' }}
                                         dropDownStyle={{ borderColor: CONSTANTS.COLOR.BASE_COLOR, backgroundColor: CONSTANTS.COLOR.DROPDOWN_BACKGROUND, textAlign: 'flext-start' }}
                                         items={cities}
                                         placeholder="Select City"
                                         placeholderStyle={{
                                              color: 'gray',
                                              textAlign: 'left'
                                         }}
                                         controller={instance => this.controller = instance}
                                         onChangeList={(cities, callback) => {
                                              this.setState({
                                                   cities // items: items
                                              }, callback);
                                         }}

                                         defaultValue={this.state.value}
                                         onChangeItem={(item, index) => this.setState({
                                              city_name: item.value, city_id: cities_with_id[index].id
                                         })}
                                    />
                               </View>

                          </View>
```

Comment: It seems like you have multiple drop downs share with one drop down states. That's why they all open at the same time. If there are only several dropdown in the components, you just need to create multiple dropdown states for each individually. There is not magic behinds the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use variables in your state that relate directly to the opening of the dropdown menus.

For example: dropdown1, dropdown2. In your first render, they should be set to *false*.

Now, whenever opening a dropdown with the function **onOpen()**, you should set the state of the dropdown you want to open to true, and the rest to false:

**Dropdown 1 example**

```
onOpen={() => { this.setState({ dropdown1: true, dropdown2: false }), this.cityOpen() }}
```

And then only show the dropdown that you need by using conditions.